# What PSU do I need for a Sega Megadrive/Genesis?

Tags: sega-genesis

I see a lot of Megadrives on sale at eBay as console only without PSU. Does the PSU have a standard shaped/sized socket? i.e. Can I buy a generic PSU to use this console, or will I need an official PSU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The power supply depends on the model.](http://www.gametrog.com/GAMETROG/How_which_do_i_need_SEGA_AC_Power_Supply_Information_Specs_Model_mk-3025_mk-1602_mk-2103_mk-1479_mk-4122_aa-s95j.html)

Wikipedia gives the connector types for two of these models:

> The power input varies depending on the model - a **model 1 uses a 2.1mm barrel connector** with a negative tip, and requires 9-10 volts DC at 1.2 A. The **model 2 uses a EIAJ-03 connector with a positive tip**, and requires 9-10 volts DC at 0.85 A .

So, going back to the chart:

- The MK-1602(-1): for use with SEGA Genesis 1, CD 1, CD 2 uses a 2.1mm barrel connector
- The MK-2103(-1): for use with SEGA Genesis 2, 32X uses a EIAJ-03 connector with a positive tip
- The MK-1479: for use with SEGA Genesis 3 *appears* to use the same connector as the MK-2103(-1), but I cannot tell. (I can't find a good photo showing the connector either)

As mentioned on the GameTrog page, be sure to match the voltage if you decide to go with a 3rd party PSU and be sure it can deliver **at least** the amount of current specified for your model.  An incorrect power supply can damage your system and potentially yourself.  **Overall, I recommend finding an official PSU.**